# Why do keyframes keep disappearing in the dopesheet?

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

I've imported an fbx with an "in place" walk cycle from mixamo.com (see below). I then parented the armature to an empty as a way of animating the "in place" walk cycle ([tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gxd42ONmU_g)).

[image]

My problem is that with the armature parented to the empty, now I can't find the walk cycle keyframes. No matter what I click on, they will not appear in the dope sheet. In the outliner below, I've clicked on where I think they would be but they don't show up. Any thoughts on why those keyframes are not showing? Unfortunately, I can't get the blend file down to a postable size.

Here's what I mean by "in place" walk cycle:

[image]

Why do all the keyframes keep disappearing?

Comment: How is the cycle performed? NLE? Modifiers? Maybe the keyframes are showing up only in the region in which the loop starts (maybe frames 1-32, you are at 888). Mabe you could upload your file deleting the meshes and leaving armatures and animations only.

Comment: Thanks Josh. It appears to be a bug. I can't reproduce it exactly. Everything seems to fine and then I'll get to work and suddenly the keyframes will no longer display. Incredibly aggravating. I just have to save a new version every minute or so as I work, until I figure out what's causing this.

Comment: Related: [Hidden keyframes in timeline](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178287/hidden-keyframes-in-timeline)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an entire year late, but this worked for me. Click the button that says "Only Show Selected" (the arrow icon!) [image: Specifically the arrow icon]

Then my keyframes appeared. Apparently they're grouped under the vertex groups or something.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Often for me the window with the keyframes is simply scrolled out of view, so when I scroll back up they are there.

Comment: Like so: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/178291/31447 ?