# Keyframes disappeared in the timeline - How do I get them back?

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

I guess I pressed a hotkey by accident and my keyframes disappeared for whatever reason. As far as I can tell the keyframes are hidden by the frame numbers numbers:

[image]

The animation still works, I can add new keyframes, but I cannot select any of them as they're hidden... Does anyone know how to get back to the default settings?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Middle click in the timeline then drag your mouse down.

I don't know why you can infinitely scroll keyframes up in this case. Sometimes they disappear and you have to drag down for quite some time to get them back.

[image]

Comment: Strange behaviour indeed. Matkers are overlaid it seems. _`View > View All`_  will  bring all kfs to view.

Answer (score 9):

With mouse cursor over your [Timeline](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/timeline.html) press <kbd>Home</kbd> on your keyboard or go to *View > Frame All*:

[image].

Same trick applies for [Dope Sheet](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/dope_sheet/index.html) (and pretty much any other view in Blender).

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility why you can't see the keyframes on the *Timeline* might be, if you've enabled the option *Only Show Errors* in the *View* menu of the *Timeline* window, than your keyframes will not show up unless there is an error.

[image: timeline view options]

Answer (score 3):

In Blender 2.8, I had to uncheck *Only Keyframes from Selected Channels* from the *View* menu. Keyframes reappeared for me.

[image]

Comment: Since the accepted answer was already given about 1.5 years ago and the object which keyframes "disappeared" was selected, this answer does not really bring any new benefits to the question...