# Keyframes disappearing

Tags: keyframes, grease-pencil

I was working on Blender for 2D animation and at some point the keyframes just disappeared. They are still there hidden because I can access my drawings but the yellow squares are not visible anymore:

[image]

Did I activate some shortcut by accident ? Or is it a bug regarding grease pencil ?

EDIT 1: The solutions given here [Hidden keyframes in timeline](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178287/hidden-keyframes-in-timeline) do not solve my problem. Scrolling up as much as I can do not bring back the keyframes, nor clicking view -> Frame all.

[image]

Normally I should see the layers below "summary" but here they just disappeared but they are still visible in the layer panel.

Comment: Hi, quite a few reasons this could be. Just to confirm, do you have keyframes for the selected object? If the layers are blank blender sometimes does this? Otherwise, have you tried selecting the object and then, with your mouse over the timeline portion, used the Tab key? (this locks and unlocks editing and sometimes hides keys)

Comment: Your advice helped me a bit. The keyframes disappeared when a was in edit mode, transforming some strokes. The layers were not blank. However, my object was not selected in the outliner. That is why my keyframes were hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned there are many possible causes but I had this problem because of some mysterious activation of the setting **Only Show Selected**, "Only include channels relating to selected objects and data." I do not know exactly why this gets set (besides obviously clicking it) but clicking its button (so that it is not the active blue color) brings back the keyframes.

[image]