# Why are my keyframes not visible in the timeline?

Tags: animation, objects, keyframes, timeline

I'm practicing on camera movements based on a tutorial by *polyjord* and I noticed that my keyframes are missing in the timeline at some point:

[image]

**Q:** How do I get my keyframes back?

Comment: Maybe this can help ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178287/hidden-keyframes-in-timeline

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I guess the comment by @Gorgious is what you're experiencing. If not, try this solution:

If you've enabled the option *Only Show Errors* in the *View* menu of the *Timeline* window, than your keyframes will not show up unless there is an error.

[image: timeline view]