# I can't see object in timeline when I added keyframes

Tags: keyframes, timeline

I insert keyframes in geometry nodes but they don't show up on the timeline or graph editor.[image]

Comment: Have you tried with the node selected?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178287/keyframes-disappeared-in-the-timeline-how-do-i-get-them-back

Comment: @L0Lock I think that was the issue, can't believe that was my mistake. Thank you.