# Nothing is shown in the Timeline

Tags: animation, shaders, keyframes, timeline

It is the first time I use blender.

I ran into an issue when I tried to insert a keyframe on the "Phase Offset" but nothing showed for the Timeline seen in the figure below. I tried to run it, but it doesn't have the looping effect.

FYI: mine is Blender 3.3.1 latest ver
[image]

This figure below is from a youtube tutorial using Blender 2.92 but his blender works like a charm.
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178287/keyframes-disappeared-in-the-timeline-how-do-i-get-them-back

Comment: In the tutorial the keyframed node is selected in the _Shader Editor_. Yours is not selected.